# Why std::uncaught_exceptions returns int but not size_t?

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

Because `std::uncaught_exceptions` returns *count* of exceptions that have been thrown, it makes no sense to have this number negative. Also, `size_t` may be bigger than `int` and thus it is less likely to be overflown.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Can `std::uncaught_exceptions` return a negative value? If so, in which conditions is this possible?
2. Why the biggest integer type was not chosen?

Comment: How many uncaught exceptions do you want a single thread to have ?  Remember that throwing a second exception whilst stack unwinding is happening and not immediately catching it will terminate the program.

Comment: Maybe one would want to call the function more than once and calculate the difference?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that there's a sizable contingent of people who would argue that `int` should have been used in most places where `size_t` is right now. (in part because the wrapping guarantees of unsigned integer prevents some optimizations)

Comment: Working with signed types has less "gotchas". And I certainly hope nobody needs to support even a signed char's worth number of exceptions, let alone `int`, and especially not `size_t`.

Comment: @Frank Indeed - and I think Bjarne Stroustrup is amongst that number.

Comment: @Frank: Is that sizable contingent so big that you need a `size_t` for its size? ;)

Comment: @Frank and the many `for (i = 0; i < collection.size() - 1; ++i) { ... };` type bugs we see here.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question as opinion-based. This is a standard library function, not some arbitrary piece of code. There is a rationale behind such decisions, and I think it has the protentional to be interesting.

Comment: fyi link to the adoption paper [N4259](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4259.pdf) not a lot there.  Link to the proposal paper https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4152.pdf nothing I can see in there on the return type.